# Is the PC/SC API accessible for the windows-phone-7 platform?

Tags: windows-phone-7, smartphone, apdu, pcsc

I browsed through the Windows Phone 7 documentation web site, and was unable to find if it is possible to write an application on this platform that can communicate with the smarphone's SIM card using APDU commands/responses (ISO7816).

Is this possible to use PC/SC or some other API for this, and if yes, where can I find some documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported on the phone.

May be able to do it with interop unlocked, but then you cannot submit for the marketplace.